# ibmcom/db2 docker image fails to initialize with "db2 command not found"

Tags: linux, docker, db2

I'm trying to run db2 in a docker container, but when inspecting the logs I keep seeing

```sh
/bin/bash: db2: command not found
```

Command used:

```sh
> docker run -itd --name test-db2 --privileged=true -p 50080:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=abcd1234 -e DBNAME=TESTDB ibmcom/db2:latest
```

I went into the container's terminal and ran:

```sh
> which db2
/usr/bin/which: no db2 in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
```

and found that it's not added to the path for the root user, but it works when switching to the **db2inst1** user:

```sh
> su - db2inst1
> which db2
~/sqllib/bin/db2
```

Note:
I haven't tried to make my own Dockerfile starting from ibmcom/db2 because I'm a complete noob in docker.

Maybe I'm missing some steps, or maybe I'm doing something else wrong, because I've tried with 5 different versions of this image and I keep getting the same error.

Has anyone faced this problem?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is correct behaviour.  You should not use the db2 clp as root for security reasons. Instead you should become a different user , such as db2inst1, or any other account whose login startup script can dot in the relevant db2profile file (in your case  . ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile) which sets various environment variables including PATH so making db2 available.

Comment: I don't see how this is correct as it leads to setup failure on the default setup script for this image. "db2: command not found" is thrown when the image tries to initialize the database. From my understanding the setup script should run under the "db2inst1" user, but it seems it runs on root.

Comment: You write "tried with 5 differen versions of this image".  Why? Some broken Dockerfile or incorrect customization possibly, or incorrect usage.   I note that todays ibmcom/db2 (built 16th 2021) behaves Correctly,  i.e. when used according to the readme instructions on dockerhub. The `docker logs -f mydb2` does not show your symptom.

Comment: I see the same issue. I run `podman run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=mypasswd -e DBNAME=testdb -v mydir:/database ibmcom/db2` and get a bunch of `db2: command not found` errors.